# how to print this array in reverse

Tags: java

i just started learning java and i'm trying to print this array in reverse
not sure what i'm doing wrong but it doesn't return the second loop, no errors

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main { 
 public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner red = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr;
        arr  = new int[3];
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter number");
            arr[i]=red.nextInt();

        }
        for (int j=2;j<0;j--) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try  `(int j=2;j>0;j--)` j is never less then zero so your second loop is not entered

Comment: @omer it should be `j > 0` in the second while loop. You should also consider using `j = arr.length - 1`.

Comment: @James Buck j should be >=0 Array indices are 0-based, that is, they start from 0

Comment: @Arin That is true xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int j = arr.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
```